# In Geometry Nodes, how can I edit two separate vector nodes in opposite directions with one slider?

Tags: vertices, vertex-groups, vector, geometry-nodes

I have a model that I'm trying to offset on the X axis. The model is separated into two different vector groups. I want the left half of the model to move in the negative direction on the X axis while the right half of the model moves in the positive direction. Ideally I would be able to control all of this with one slider.

[image]

Is there a way to invert the value of one of these nodes? I want them to always be offset by the same amount, just in opposite directions.

[image]

Is it possible to link these two vector math nodes together somehow so that when a slider is used, one vector is offset by -1 while another is offset by +1?

Comment: add node "Scale"，and set the value to -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  One flexible way that I like is to use an *Input* node for the slider.  Feed it directly to one of the *Vector math* nodes.  Feed it to a *Math* node set to *Multiply* and use -1 as the multiplier.  In this version I've added a *combineXYZ* node for flexibility:

[image: Node group described above]

This way, the *Input* slider directly drives both Add nodes but in opposite directions.

Comment: THANK YOU! This is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: @CosmicVfx  You're very welcome.